# Simple navbar in pure HTML5 and CSS3

Tags: html, css

With some effort I've managed to build a very simple (maybe too simple haha) navigation bar for a website.

Is it possible to make a transition on the dropwdown list from height:0 to some suitable height? I've tried and it seems not to be possible. **No javascript for now**

Any advice or extra tweak I could add? All is greatly welcome!

```css
        /* reset */
        ul {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;

        }

        /* automatically take height of the elements */
        .main {
            background-color: brown;
            overflow: auto;
            /* automatically adjusts height to anchors */
        }

        .main__lis {
            margin-left: 20px;
            float: left;
            /* float the list items of the main ul */
        }

        a {
            display: block;
            padding: 10px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .dropdown ul {
            width: 120px;
            text-align: left;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: pink;
            display: none;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        }


        .dropdown:hover ul {
            display: block;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <nav>
        <ul class='main'>
            <li class='main__lis'><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class='main__lis'><a href="#">News</a></li>
            <li class='main__lis dropdown'>
                <a href="#">Dropdown</a>
                <ul class='dropdown_ul'>
                    <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you wanting feedback on the design (probably off topic here), or just code?

Comment: @dwjohnston just code. Any design advice would be welcome though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to reset the margin and padding of `li` items, too.

Using `float` to layout elements horizontally is outdated. Using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) should be preferred nowadays. That would also make `overflow: auto` redundant.

Prefer a child combinator instead of a descendant combinator if possible: `.dropdown > ul`.

A dropdown on hover isn't usable on a touch screen.

Comment: why that sentence about combinators?

Comment: A descendant combinator is more work for the browser. It has to look at all elements above each `ul` element to look for an element with the class `dropdown`, but with a child combinator it only needs to look the direct parent element.

Comment: Nice one. Thanks. btw I know about flexbox but wouldn't floats be preferable as a matter of support?

Comment: Even if you need to support older browsers like IE9, then you still should use flexbox and add a separate stylesheet for them.

Answer (score 0):

all a tags have a padding of 10 according to you css. the `<li>` tags have anchor tags @RoTaRa's suggestion "Prefer a child combinator instead of a descendant combinator if possible: `.dropdown > ul.`" make sure, you use `!important` for the new padding; i.e.  `padding: 0px!important;`

Comment: If you use `!important` like that, then you are structuring your CSS wrong. `!important` must always be the last resort.

Comment: If it works without !important, then, by all means, don't add it. but if another class is overriding your style, then last resort